# Oracle Data Export to Access / SQL-Server-Backup

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, ms-access

I am looking for a (simple) tool/possibility, which exports an Oracle database (only the tables, no constraints) with low effort (one-click) to an mdb-File (Access) and/or SQLServer-Backup-File.

Comment: does it have to be free as well as simple?  which versions?

Answer (score 0):

If it's just the data your after then I think the best approach would be to spool your tables out to individual .txt files.  This should then allow them to be imported with relative ease into any database you choose. I recommend writing a .sql file to perform the actions which could be run using SQL*Plus which is part of the Oracle suite.